# How to pass a collection to a directive in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please forgive my lack of understanding.

I pass the name of a collection to my directive:

```
   <ul tag-it tag-src="preview_data.preview.extract.keywords"><li>Tag 1</li><li>Tag 2</li></ul>
```

The directive is defined:

```
app.directive('tagIt', function (){
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,elem, attr) {

            elem.tagit();
            console.log(attr.tagSrc); //the name of my collection, but how do I access it?
        }
    }
});
```

How do I access my collection from the directive and make sure my directive is called when the collection is populated? Here is `how preview_data.preview.extract.keyword`s gets populated.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    console.log('config');
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/templates/addItem.html",
        controller: "AddItemController",
        resolve: {
            loadData: addItemCtrl.loadData

        }
    });
});

var addItemCtrl=app.controller("AddItemController", function ($scope, $route, $sce, Preview) {
    var title = decodeURIComponent($route.current.params.title);
    var ua = decodeURIComponent($route.current.params.ua);
    var uri = decodeURIComponent($route.current.params.uri);
    $scope.preview_data = {
        uri: uri,
        title: title,
        ua: ua
    }
    //pass parameters to web preview API

    Preview.get(uri, ua, title).then(function (data) {

        $scope.preview_data.preview = data;
        if (data.embed.html) {
            $scope.preview_data.preview.embed.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.embed.html);
        }
    }, function (data) {
        alert('Error: no data returned')
    });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the variable in the directive scope and set the template to iterate between the tags:

```
        template : '<li data-ng-repeat="tag in tagSrc">{{tag.name}}</li>',
        scope : {
          tagSrc : '='
        },
```

And will became this:

```
   app.directive('tagIt', function (){
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        template : '<li data-ng-repeat="tag in tagSrc">{{tag.name}}</li>',
        scope : {
          tagSrc : '='
        },

        link: function(scope,elem, attr) {

            console.log(attr.tagSrc); 
        }
    }
});
```

the `'='` attribute will tells to angular to use a tw way binding with the array passed in the directive declaration in the HTML.

[Here is a plunker with a working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/yKgFYLcFqFX3epVY87aA?p=preview)

And [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives) is a good arcticle explaning the directive's attributes and life cycle.

I hope it helps.

**[EDIT]**

If you want just iterate the array, without creating some different behavior in the list items,  you can just simply use the ng-repeat directive:

```
<ul>
     <li data-ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag.name}}</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: This is a model answer! Thanks. In my case, I can't use ng-repeat because what I am doing is really wrapping a jQuery plugin. I need to actually construct a snippet of HTML and add it to the DOM using `elem.html()`, so that when I apply `elem.tagIt()`, the jQuery function `.tagIt` will do its transform stuff. But I cannot figure out how to access tagSrc. I see it in the object in console, but can't get at its accessor. I'll ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Follow on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645531/how-to-access-scope-collection-object-in-directive-to-manually-construct-html-sn

Comment: Thanks! I see the question now but it notice that you have a solution =) nice!