# How to access scope collection object in directive to manually construct HTML snippet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Follow on question from [How to pass a collection to a directive in angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626098/how-to-pass-a-collection-to-a-directive-in-angular-js)

I can't use ng-repeat inside my directive template, because I am need to manually construct an HTML snippet to pass to a jQuery plugin that I am wrapping in a directive. https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

In the example below, I either need to 1) find a way to apply elem.tagIt() AFTER the template is rendered, or 2) access tagSrc WITHIN the directive to construct that HTML snippet and then add it to elem.html() before applying elem.tagIt().

```
app.directive('tagIt', function (){
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { tagSrc: '='},
        template: '<li data-ng-repeat="tag in tagSrc">{{tag.name}}</li>',
        link: function(scope,elem, attr) {
            //tagIt() is a reference to jQuery plugin that turns LIs in to stackoverflow-style tags
            elem.tagit(); //tagIt is not applied to the right DOM contents because ng-repeat hasn't written it out yet
            console.log(attr.tagSrc);
        }
```

}
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags will be accessible through `scope.tagSrc` but they maybe not ready yet when your directive is linking.

In order to call tag it when tagSrc changes, use `scope.$watch`:

```
scope.$watch('tagSrc', function(){
  elem.tagIt();
});
```

Comment: I had to use this version because my tag list is getting populated by an asynchronous service call, so only by watching tagSrc to wait until it is populated could I detect when to fire. tagit(). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap plugin calls or DOM manipulation code within `$timeout` . This assures digest cycle is complete and new element exists when plugin is initialized

```
app.directive('tagIt', function ($timeout){
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { tagSrc: '='},
        template: '<li data-ng-repeat="tag in tagSrc">{{tag.name}}</li>',
        link: function(scope,elem, attr) {
           $timeout(function(){
              elem.tagit(); 
               console.log(attr.tagSrc);

           },1)
        }

   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    // do something with third party library
    elem.tagit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting my answer here for posterity:

```
app.directive('tagIt', function (){
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { tagSrc: '='},
        link: function(scope,elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch('tagSrc', function(){
                if (!(typeof scope.tagSrc=='undefined')) { //wait til we are populated
                    console.log(scope.tagSrc);
                    var li='';
                    _.each(scope.tagSrc,function(tag) {
                        li+='<li>'+tag.name+'</li>';

                    });
                    elem.html(li);
                    elem.tagit(); //tagIt() is a reference to jQuery plugin that turns LIs in to stackoverflow-style tags

                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```